Why does "find . -type d -empty -mtime +7 -delete" produce "No such file or directory" error messages?
I've found similar questions being answered, where the find command encounters errors deleting files. However, the most similar question with an answer on Stack Exchange is regarding the find -type d -exec rmdir {} \; command. People have recommended using the find command with -delete instead because the -delete option implies -depth, which has the find command use depth-first search to delete files.
That makes sense to me, but I am using the command people recommend find . -type d -empty -mtime +7 -delete to delete empty directories older than 7 days old. Yet, I still encounter the error No such file or directory.
Interestingly, when I go to the directories that do not exist, I cannot find them. Is it deleting the directories despite the error?

(it always does a depth-first search, it's just a question of preordering vs. postordering the dirs)

Try adding -print before the -delete so perhaps you'll be able to tell what directory supposedly doesn't exist.

The most likely reason you get a No such file or directory error is that the directory did not exist at the time find tried to delete it.  But it wouldn't try to delete it if it didn't exist when it scanned...
So the most likely explanation is that something else deleted the directory between when find saw it and when find got around to trying to delete it.  For example, this would occur if you ran the same find command twice in parallel.
